# Changing the initial size of log files

Tags: sql-server

I am changing the initial size of log files but it goes back to its previous size. Can somebody please let me know what do I need to do so that it gets the new size?

Thanks

Comment: The *initial size* is not actually the initial size its misleading thing, I am sure you are trying to change it using GUI please try to change it via T SQL and see what message you get

Answer (score 1):

If a SQL log file size reduces unexpectedly:

- Disable the auto-shrink option on the DB if it is set (a best practice anyway)
- Look for maintenance plans with a Shrink Log step and remove that step for your DB
- Look for SQL Agent jobs that are shrinking log files, and modify them to exclude your DB

[Edit] Background, question was asked here initially: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173010/change-the-initial-size-of-log-files

Issue is log being increased to 2GB, but automagically shrinking.

Comment: How does this answers original question